# My dice are rioting; how do I get them to stop?

Tags: dice-legacy

It seems I've made my peasant dice unhappy.  Even though they survived the winter (albeit mostly in suspended animation) and some new faces appeared, apparently I rejected their wise proposals at the council, and also lost one or two or three along the way from overwork.

Now I'm told that if I don't stop this riot, I'll lose.

But how do I stop the riot?

[image: The peasants are angry]